# Enviar POST a PHP por medio de AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Necesito que al hacer clic en un botón por medio de POST me envíe un dato a un archivo PHP donde hago una consulta con ese parámetro que recibo para generar una gráfica. Lo he hecho por medio de un form, pero surge un inconveniente al hacer clic en ese botón: se debe abrir un modal con la gráfica adentro. Por lo tanto no se puede recargar la pagina.

He leído que se puede hacer con AJAX, pero nunca lo he usado y no lo entiendo mucho. No sé de qué otras maneras pueda realizar un POST sin necesidad de recargar la página.

Mi proyecto usa jQuery.

Answer (score 17):

Usando jquery es relativamente sencillo usar ajax, a continuación te coloco un ejemplo sencillo:

Este sería tu archivo HTML donde haces la llamada ajax

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Ejemplo sencillo de AJAX</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function realizaProceso(valorCaja1, valorCaja2){
        var parametros = {
                "valorCaja1" : valorCaja1,
                "valorCaja2" : valorCaja2
        };
        $.ajax({
                data:  parametros, //datos que se envian a traves de ajax
                url:   'ejemplo_ajax_proceso.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
                type:  'post', //método de envio
                beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#resultado").html("Procesando, espere por favor...");
                },
                success:  function (response) { //una vez que el archivo recibe el request lo procesa y lo devuelve
                        $("#resultado").html(response);
                }
        });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
Introduce valor 1
<input type="text" name="caja_texto" id="valor1" value="0"/> 
Introduce valor 2
<input type="text" name="caja_texto" id="valor2" value="0"/>
Realiza suma
<input type="button" href="javascript:;" onclick="realizaProceso($('#valor1').val(), $('#valor2').val());return false;" value="Calcula"/>
<br/>
Resultado: <span id="resultado">0</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Ademas de este archivo tiene que tener un archivo que procese la petición ajax, este caso se llama **ejemplo_ajax_proceso.php**, este archivo contendrá lo siguiente:

```
<?php 
$resultado = $_POST['valorCaja1'] + $_POST['valorCaja2']; 
echo $resultado; //haciendo este echo estas respondiendo la solicitud ajax
?>
```

Intenta probando ese código, así tendrás una idea de como funciona ajax.

Answer (score 8):

Hace tiempo escribí un post en un blog acerca de esto, si quieres probarlo es mas o menos asi:

Este seria tu `html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title> Acción onclick en js </title>
    // Aquí esta la referencia a jquery
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" id="formulario">
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" autofocus/>
        <input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
        <input type="button" id="btn-ingresar" value="Ingresar" />
    </form>
    // Este div nos servirá para cachar la respuesta enviada 
    // por el backend en caso de que sea necesario.
    <div id="resp"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

y aquí tienes la acción del botón que enviará los datos de tu formulario a tu archivo `php`:

```
$(document).on('ready',function(){       
    $('#btn-ingresar').click(function(){
        var url = "datos_login.php";
        $.ajax({                        
           type: "POST",                 
           url: url,                     
           data: $("#formulario").serialize(), 
           success: function(data)             
           {
             $('#resp').html(data);               
           }
       });
    });
});
```

Esta es una parte de lo que vendría siendo tu archivo `php` llamada en este ejemplo como `datos_login.php`:

```
<?php   
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $contra  = $_POST['contrasena'];

    echo "tu usuario es: ".$usuario; 
    echo "contraseña es: ".$contrsena;
?>
```

checalo y si tienes dudas puedes consultar la referencia del post que escribí [aquí](http://josegoyo.github.io/2015-11-13-envio-ajax).

El código completo quedaría mas o menos así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title> Acción onclick en js </title>
    // Aquí esta la referencia a jquery
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).on('ready',function(){

      $('#btn-ingresar').click(function(){
        var url = "datos_login.php";                                      

        $.ajax({                        
           type: "POST",                 
           url: url,                    
           data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
           success: function(data)            
           {
             $('#resp').html(data);           
           }
         });
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" id="formulario">
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario" autofocus/>
        <input type="password" name="contrasena" placeholder="Contraseña"/>
        <input type="button" id="btn-ingresar" value="Ingresar" />
    </form>
    // Este div nos servirá para cachar la respuesta enviada 
    // por el backend en caso de que sea necesario.
    <div id="resp"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Hola sabes por que me recarga la pagina? osea hace la peticion y la respuesta la tengo con una alert, lo cual deberia detener el flujo de ejecucion, pero no, la recarga inmediatamente, y si le pongo en el form el action me vuelve a redireccionar a la url que este en el action, sabrias por que ?

Answer (score 0):

lo que necesitas es detectar tanto el `click` del `que hace 2 acciones` enviar `formulario` y detectar que se `envie el form` en todo caso primero desactivas el `form` de esta manera.

```
//detectamos el envio
$(document).on("submit","#idform",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();//detenemos el envio
    $("#myModal").modal();//dispara el modal equivale-> [ data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" ]
    $.post("api/ruta/post.php",$("#idform").serialize(),function(res){
        $("#cargapost").html(res);//cargamos todo el resultado de la peticion en el 'div' que queremos, donde [id="cargapost"] se encuenta en el cuerpo del 'modal'
    });
    //$.post -> envia como POST, $.get -> envia GET
    //$("#idform").serialize() -> toma todos los campos del formulario identificando por el nombre [name="nombre"]
    //
})
```

esto detecta que el formulario se esta enviando y lo `cancela`, ya no se recarga la pagina.

```html
  <form action="" id="idform">
   nombre
   <input type="text" name="nombre" class="form-control"><!-- usamos 'name para identificar' -->
   valor
   <input type="text" name="valor" class="form-control">

   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">   
  </form>
    <!-- Nuestro modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
       
         <!-- Modal Header -->
         <div class="modal-header">
           <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
         </div>
         
         <!-- Modal body -->
         <div class="modal-body">
          <div id="cargapost"></div> <!-- campo para cargar resultado -->
         </div>
         
         <!-- Modal footer -->
         <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         </div>
         
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var url = 'aqui la url';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        load();

$('form').submit(function (e) {
                $.post(url, {mivariable: $('#clasedelinput').val(),  }); 
                $('#clasedelinput').val('');
                return false;
```

Ya es muy tarde pero seguro le puede servir a quien vino buscando una respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, sin embargo editarla y agregarla daría mucha calidad a tu respuesta para comprender mejor como esto soluciona el problema