# ¿Como enviar formulario cake php por Ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-bake

Quisiera saber como puedo enviar un formulario via ajax al controller de mi vista cabemensionar que uso cakephp:

**Vista**

```
<div class="usuarios form large-9 medium-8 columns content">
    <?= $this->Form->create() ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?= __('Add Usuario') ?></legend>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->control('nombre');
            echo $this->Form->control('correo');
            echo $this->Form->control('contrasena');
            echo $this->Form->control('tipo');
            echo $this->Form->control('fecha_creacion');
            echo $this->Form->control('fecha_sesion');
        ?>
    </fieldset>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit')) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
</div>
```

y la informacion que me llegue a mi controlador:

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function add()
    {
        $usuario = $this->Usuarios->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $usuario = $this->Usuarios->patchEntity($usuario, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Usuarios->save($usuario)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('The usuario has been saved.'));

                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('The usuario could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
        $this->set(compact('usuario'));
    }
```

ESPERO ALGUIEN PUEDA AYUDARME

Comment: Para enviarlo mediante ajax tienes que usar javascript ¿Estás usando jQuery?

Comment: no, no  estoy usando nada aun lei que para usar ajax  debo de usar helpers del lado del controlador la verdad que soy completamente nueva con el framework

Comment: No necesariamente, lo que pasa que ajax [se ejecuta en el cliente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) por lo que debes agarrar la información de la form y enviarla mediante javascript, te sugiero que te des una vuelta por [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24583/enviar-post-a-php-por-medio-de-ajax), en la `url` pondrías `/usuarios/add`, de esta forma puedes enviar la información al servidor y manejarla según sean tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres crear formularios por javascript, te recomendaría que utilizaras un framework como VueJs, angular o la librería de React, y utilizar el increíble CakePHP para generar las Apis de los controladores de tus modelos de base de datos.

si quieres usar Jquery es más engorroso, pero obviamente posible:

de entrada en el controlador para poder mandar cosas por ajax tendrías de desabilitar el security component del formulario:

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
     $this->Security->setConfig('unlockedActions', ['add', 'edit', 'delete']); // o los que te hagas
}
```

y luego poner el código ajax:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    // Al clicar ek submit
    $('form').submit(function(event) {

        // metes en una variable los datos de formulario,  ojo tiene que estar igual de como los llamaste para hacer el CRUD en cakephp
        var formData = {
            'name'              : $('input[name=name]').val(),
            'email'             : $('input[name=email]').val(),
            'superheroAlias'    : $('input[name=superheroAlias]').val()
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', // define el tipo de metodo
            url         : '/usuarios/add', // la url de tru controlador y acción
            data        : formData, // el objeto
            dataType    : 'json', // de tipo json
                        encode          : true
        })
            // usas una promesa de callback
            .done(function(data) {

                // y miras q se mandan bien los datos
                console.log(data); 

                //
            });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Muy importante, de hecho lo más importante habilita para poder mandar fomularios json.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/rest.html

```
    // src/Controller/RecipesController.php
class UsuariosController extends AppController
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $usuarios = $this->Usuarios->find('all');
        $this->set([
            'usuarios' => $usuarios,
            '_serialize' => ['usuarios']
        ]);
    }

    public function view($id)
    {
        $usuario = $this->Usuarios->get($id);
        $this->set([
            'usuario' => $usuario,
            '_serialize' => ['usuario']
        ]);
    }

    public function add()
    {
        $recipe = $this->Usuarios->newEntity($this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Usuarios->save($recipe)) {
            $message = 'Saved';
        } else {
            $message = 'Error';
        }
        $this->set([
            'message' => $message,
            'recipe' => $usuario,
            '_serialize' => ['message', 'usuario']
        ]);
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $recipe = $this->Usuarios->get($id);
        if ($this->request->is(['post', 'put'])) {
            $recipe = $this->Usuarios->patchEntity($recipe, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Usuarios->save($recipe)) {
                $message = 'Saved';
            } else {
                $message = 'Error';
            }
        }
        $this->set([
            'message' => $message,
            '_serialize' => ['message']
        ]);
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $recipe = $this->Usuarios->get($id);
        $message = 'Deleted';
        if (!$this->Usuarios->delete($recipe)) {
            $message = 'Error';
        }
        $this->set([
            'message' => $message,
            '_serialize' => ['message']
        ]);
    }
}
```

Y las routas claro:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routing-file-extensions

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    // Prior to 3.5.0 use `extensions()`
    $routes->setExtensions(['json', 'xml']);
});
```

Para más info:

esto esta muy bueno:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/submitting-ajax-forms-with-jquery