# Mandar dos fechas como parametro desde javascript ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter-3

Tengo el siguiente boton el cual manda a una funcion JS y entra correctamente

```html
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="filtrar()"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i> Filtrar</button>
```

Esta es mi funcion JS

```js
var save_metodo; //guarda el metodo cadena
    var tabla;

    function filtrar() {
      save_metodo = 'filtrar';

      validar(save_metodo);
    }

    function validar($funcion) {
      var url;

      var txtDateInicio = document.getElementById('date_inicio').value;
      var txtDateFin = document.getElementById('date_fin').value;
   
      //var banderaRBTN = false;
    
      //Test campo obligatorio
      if(txtDateInicio === '' && txtDateFin === ''){
        alert('esta vacio');
        //return false;
      } else{
        if ($funcion === 'filtrar') {
          url = "<?=base_url('index.php/login_controller/perfil_calls')?>/";
          alert(url);
        }else if ($funcion === 'export_pdf') {
          url = "<?=base_url('index.php/login_controller/generar_pdf/')?>";
        } else {
          url = "<?=base_url('index.php/login_controller/gererar_excel')?>";
        }

        // ajax
          $.ajax({
            url : url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
               location.reload();
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('Error al filtrar');
            }
        });

      }

    }
```

Necesito enviar como parametro  txtDateInicio y txtDateFin a la variable URL pero no me esta quedando, esta entrando al error.

Mi funcion del controlador donde debo recibir las fechas como parametro (no necesariamente tiene que se como parametro).

```
public function perfil_calls($date_inicio, $date_fin) {
  $data = array();
  $data['calls'] = $this->login_model->rango_calls($date_inicio, $date_fin);

  $this->load->view('perfil_view.php', $data);
}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Gracias

Comment: Yo no veo que este enviando data desde ajax, donde esta `data` ?

Comment: en el succes hay un data, como busque el ajax en internet la verdad no se para que funcione el data que recibe como para metro en el success

Comment: el success es la respuesta del servidor en base a una petición hecha con ajax , por que data solo sería un nombre que le das, por otra parte, el data que te menciono va en la declaración de el ajax junto con url,type y dataType , [Ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517071/send-json-data-via-post-ajax-and-receive-json-response-from-controller-mvc)

Comment: El data que tienes en el success es el resultado de tu petición ajax, es decir lo que devuelve el server, y para enviar las fechas al server debes agregar algo como -- data : {fecha1: txtDateInicio, fecha2: txtDateFin}, -- Justo como mencionan en el comentario anterior. Te dejo un link donde explican como funciona ajax: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24583/enviar-post-a-php-por-medio-de-ajax

Comment: Ya lo intente y aun sigue sin funcionar, entra al error