# Como puedo cargar datos a unos campos de texto html cuando el primero pierde el enfoque?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html5, web

tengo un pequeño conflicto con un proyecto en el que estoy trabajando.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resulta que necesito cargar el código de un material, y cuando este pierda el enfoque se debe realizar una busqueda en la base de datos, tome los datos de la tabla Materiales y los cargue a los dos campos que muestro en mi formulario.

Me resulta dificil, ya que las consultas las hago con php, pero no puedo llamar una funcion php desde el evento OnBlur, no se por que no me funciona.

desde ya, agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Necesitas usar AJAX para hacer ese tipo de consultas. Puedes revisar [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24583/enviar-post-a-php-por-medio-de-ajax) pregunta para orientarte un poco

Comment: AJAX es la solucion busca un poquito mas como funciona ajax con php

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta, la verdad, aun no manejo nada de ajax, lo investigaré. Saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

con **ajax** pudes hacer facilmente lo que te propones la sintaxis es cencilla y no hay que escribir mucho codigo, seria algo como..

```
 $(document).on('ready',function(){       
     $('#tu-input').on("blur",function(){
          var url = "traer_datos.php";
          $.ajax({                        
             type: "POST",                 
             url: url,                     
             data: $("#formulario").serialize(),//aqui mandarias el valor que quieras enviar para hacer la consulta 
             dataType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',//debes indicar al ajax que el callback se tratara de un json 
            success: function(data){

           //si la consulta tiene exito ejecutas el codigo que nececites ejemplo
         //puedes inprimir en los inputs el valor del callback asi mas o menos

             $("input").attr("value",data["clave"])  
                   }
               });
            });
        });
```

y en tu archivo **php** capturas el valor que envias atraves de **ajax**

```
  <?php   
      $valor= $_POST['x-valor'];

       /*aqui harias tu en base al valor recivido*/
      $sql="SELECT * FROM tuTabla WHERE tuCampo='$valor'";
     /*ejecutar consulta*/
     $query=mysqli_query($link,$sql);//estoy asumiendo que tu variable de conexion a la base de datos se llama $link
      /*si la consulta es exitosa*/
    if($query){
       /*leemos la consulta para imprimirla*/
         $row=mysqli_fetch_array($query);
         $variable=$row["tu_campo_que_decees"];

      /*envias el valor que quieras en un array clave valor este seria el callback*/
        echo json_encode(array("clave"=>$variable));
     }
        ?>
```

espero aclararte algunas dudas puedes seguir invetigando sobre **ajax** y **php** [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289078/parse-json-from-jquery-ajax-success-data) ´para que veas mas o menos como funciona, suerte!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo. es la solucion que buscaba, bien sencilla, lo probe y funciono a la perfeccion. SALUDOS!!

Comment: me alegro que te funciono saludos y sigue practicando!!