# Cómo recorrer tabla html y obtener los valores mediante POST en otro archivo para insertar en base de datos

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, ajax

Tengo esta tabla `html` donde al hacer *click* en el botón **"Guardar Todo"** la recorro y necesito insertar todos los datos en una **base de datos**. El recorrerla y traer los datos; lo hace bien; pero no sé cómo hacer el *POST* de esos datos para poder insertarlos en la **base de datos**. Realizo un `console.log($(this).text());` que me trae bien los datos que están en la tabla `html` y me los muestra en la *consola*. Aca abajo agrego el código `html` y el *script* de mi archivo y además agrego el código del archivo donde intento hacer el *POST* y el *insert*. Alguna solución? Desde ya muchas gracias.

```js
$("#b2").click(function () {
            $("td").each(function () {
                console.log($(this).text());

                var producto = $(this).find('td').eq(0).val();
                var cantidad = $(this).find('td').eq(1).val();
                var medida = $(this).find('td').eq(2).val();
                var fecha = $(this).find('td').eq(3).val();
                var turno = $(this).find('td').eq(4).val();
                
                

                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "leer_tabla.php",
                    data: "producto=" + producto + "&cantidad=" + cantidad + "&medida=" + medida + "&fecha=" + fecha + "&turno=" + turno,

                    success: function () {
                        alert('listo');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
        
        
        
        
        
function guardar() {

                var producto = $('select[name="producto"] option:selected').text();
                var cantidad = document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
                var medida = $('select[name="medida"] option:selected').text();
                var fecha = document.getElementById("fecha").value;
                var turno = document.getElementById("turno").value;

                var fila = "<tr><td>" + producto + "</td><td>" + cantidad + "</td><td>" + medida + "</td><td>" + fecha + "</td><td>" + turno + "</td></tr>";

                var btn = document.createElement("TR");
                btn.innerHTML = fila;
                document.getElementById("tablita").appendChild(btn);
            }
```

```html
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" id="register_form">

                <!-- Form Name -->
                <legend>Vender Producto</legend>
                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Producto</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <select class="form-control" name="producto" id="producto" required>
                            <option disabled selected value ></option>
                            <?php
                            $clavebuscadah = mysql_query("select productos.id_prod, productos.prod_nomb, unidad_medida.unme_nomb FROM productos INNER JOIN unidad_medida ON productos.id_unid_medi=unidad_medida.id_unid_medi ORDER BY prod_nomb ASC", $link) or
                                    die("Problemas en el select:" . mysql_error());
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($clavebuscadah)) {
                                echo'<OPTION VALUE="' . $row['id_prod'] . '">' . $row['prod_nomb'] . ' {' . $row['unme_nomb'] . '} </OPTION>';
                                //$categoria = $row['cate_nomb'];
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div><br>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Cantidad</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text"  name="cantidad" id="cantidad" class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Un.Medida</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">

                        <select class="form-control" name="medida" id="medida" required>
                            <option disabled selected value ></option>
                            <?php
                            $clavebuscadah = mysql_query("select * from unidad_medida", $link) or
                                    die("Problemas en el select:" . mysql_error());
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($clavebuscadah)) {
                                echo'<OPTION VALUE="' . $row['id_unid_medi'] . '">' . $row['unme_nomb'] . ' </OPTION>';
                                //$categoria = $row['cate_nomb'];
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div><br>

                <!-- Text input-->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Fecha</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input class="form-control" id="fecha" type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d') ?>" disabled>
                    </div>
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Turno</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input class="form-control" id="turno" value="MAÑANA" type="text" disabled>

                    </div>
                </div><br>

                <button id="btn_guardar" onclick="guardar()">Añadir</button><br><br>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary filterable">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">Listado de Productos Vendidos</h3>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-filter"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span> Filtro</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table-wrapper-scroll-y">
                            <table id="table-2" class="table table-hover ">
                                <style>
                                    .table-wrapper-scroll-y {
                                        display: block;
                                        max-height: 250px;
                                        overflow-y: auto;
                                        -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
                                    }
                                </style>
                                <button id="guardar-table-2">Guardar todo</button><br><br>
                                <input class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar-table-2" value="Guardar Registro" type="submit" name="submit">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="filters">
                                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" disabled></th>
                                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cantidad" disabled></th>
                                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Unidad de medida" disabled></th>
                                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Fecha" disabled></th>
                                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Turno" disabled></th>

                                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Acciones" disabled></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id="tablita">

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           
        </div>
```

Comment: Por que no pasas tu json como una variable de tipo texto, una vez que estés del lado del back, realizas la deserealización y generas el insert!

Comment: Como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Porque siento que al hacer el post con ajax al otro archivo no me direcciona porque no hace anda

Comment: Construiste un api rest, en tu archivo leer tabla.php?

Comment: Bueno leer_tabla.php tiene que contener un método post, el cual debe de recibir la información del HTML, es importante que le coloques el mismo número y nombre de variables al archivo PHP y los que envías desde el HTML, si no pasas el mismo número de parámetros o el nombre cambia no se va a poder recibir la informacion!, Una vez que ya la recibes en tu PHP puedes tratarla como tu lo requieras!

Comment: ahi agregue el codigo de mi archivo leer_tabla.php aqui como respuesta. Ese es todo el codigo que tengo en ese archivo,, no sabria como pasarlo por post, recibirlo e insertarlo

Comment: ponlo como comentario, por que si no te van a poner puntos malos

Comment: require_once 'funciones.php';
$link = conectarse();
session_start();
ob_start();
$producto=$_POST['data'];
$cantidad=$_POST['cantidad'];
$medida=$_POST['medida'];
$fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
$turno=$_POST['turno'];

$query_insert_prod_vend = "INSERT INTO productos_vendidos (`id_prod`, `fecha`, `cantidad`, `id_turno`, `id_unid_medi`, `id_empl`, `total`) VALUES ('" . $producto . "','" . $fecha . "','" . $cantidad . "','" . $turno . "','" . $medida . "' ,'" . $empleado . "','" . $total . "')";
$result4 = mysql_query($query_insert_prod_vend) or die('No se pudo ejecutar');

Comment: estas mandando mal cuando envías los parametros es:  data: { 
        'foo': 'bar', 
        'ca$libri': 'no$libri' // <-- the $ sign in the parameter name seems unusual, I would avoid it
    }

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5046930/jquery-send-string-as-post-parameters

Comment: una vez que cambies tus parametros, ya debes de estar recibiendo los datos

Comment: para leer el contenido del td usa .text(), .val() es para el atributo value

Answer (score 0):

Los parámetros no los estas enviando correctamente.
data:{'parametro1':'valor1', 'parametro2':'valor2'}

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
// make sure you respect the same origin policy with this url:
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy
url: 'http://nakolesah.ru/',
data: { 
    'foo': 'bar', 
    'ca$libri': 'no$libri' // <-- the $ sign in the parameter name seems unusual, I would avoid it
},
success: function(msg){
    alert('wow' + msg);
}
});
```

Comment: Me podrias explicar que corresponde a cada variable? Si son variables que inventaste o no..
data: { 
    'foo': 'bar', 
    'ca$libri': 'no$libri' 
},

Comment: Digamos como seria mi 'data' de acuerdo al codigo que puse en este posteo?

Comment: Este post esta en español https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24583/enviar-post-a-php-por-medio-de-ajax

Comment: Si, de esa manera lo se hacer, pero los saca de inputs a los datos, yo necesito que me los saque de una tabla html a toda la fila de esa tabla y enviarla por post para insertar esa fila en la base de datos. Agradezco mucho tu respuestas

Comment: Ves que de tu tabla generas un JSON pasa todo ese JSON como una sola variable string, entonces ya del lado del PHP la conviertes a un objeto JSON array lo iteras, entonces te va a regresar Row por Row, y ya haces el insert de cada row

Comment: Me podrias dar un ejemplo con mi codigo?