# Cambiar datos en BD

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, mysqli

Voy a re-formular mi pregunta en base a lo que he conseguido y lo que necesito a ver si esta vez lo consigo explicar correctamente.

quiero poder cambiar el valor de la columna item de la imagen de abajo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A traves del boton de modificar que me lleva a otra ventana he conseguido poder modificar el valor de la linea pero me sobrescribe la linea que le asigno

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

yo lo que quiero es que al asignar a "A" la linea 3 que a "CARROXS" se le asigne la linea 1 o en su defecto que "linvidperxs" pase a ser el 1 "carroxs" el 2 y "A" el 3.

el formulario que uso para hacer el cambio se ve como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el codigo del formulario que actualmente estoy modificando es este:

```
<?php
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
  header('Pragma: no-cache');
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
//include("../sesion.php");
  require("../fpdf/documento_comun.php");
  include ("../conectar.php");


  $numdocumentotmp = $_GET["numdocumentotmp"];
  $numelinea = $_GET["numlinea"];
  $bandera = $_GET["modificado"];
//print_r($_GET);

  if (isset($bandera)) {
    $sql = "update " . $tablalineatmp . " set codigo='" . $_GET["codigo"] . "', codfamilia='" . $_GET["codfam"] . "', cantidad=" . $_GET["cantidad"] . ", precio=" . $_GET["precio"] . ", importe=" . $_GET["importe"] . ",dcto=" . $_GET["dcto"] . "
        ,descripcion='" . utf8_decode($_GET["descrip"]) . "' WHERE numdocumento=" . $numdocumentotmp . " AND numlinea=" . $numelinea;
    $rs_sql = $con->query($sql);

    echo "<script language='javascript'> window.opener.recarga(" . $_GET["importe"] . ");</script>";
    //echo "<script>window.opener.location.href='frame_lineas.php?numdocumentotmp=".$numdocumentotmp."&serie=".$serie."';</script>";
    echo "<script language='javascript'> parent.window.close();</script>";
  } else {
    $consulta = "select * FROM " . $tablalineatmp . " WHERE numdocumento=" . $numdocumentotmp . " AND numlinea=" . $numelinea;
    $rs_lineas = $con->query($consulta);
    $row= $rs_lineas->fetch_assoc();
    $numlinea = $row['numlinea'];
    $codigo = $row['codigo'];
    $codfam = $row['codfamilia'];
    $descripcion = $row['descripcion'];
    $cantidad = $row['cantidad'];
    $precio = $row['precio'];
    $importe = $row['importe'];
    $dcto = $row['dcto'];
    if (!empty($dcto)) {
      $dcto = 0;
    }
    $descrip = "'" . $descripcion . "'";
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <link href="../estilos/estilos.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
          <style>
              .cajaExtraGrande {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #696969;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    color: #000000;
    font: 8pt helvetica;
    height: 15pt;
    width: 740px;
}
          </style>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        //                var miPopup
        function aceptar(){
          var numlinea=document.getElementById("numlinea").value;
          var codigo=document.getElementById("codigo").value;
          var codfam=document.getElementById("codfam").value;
          var cantidad=document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
          var precio=document.getElementById("precio").value;
          var importe=document.getElementById("importe").value;
          var descrip=document.getElementById("descrip").value;
          var dcto=document.getElementById("dcto").value;
          //alert (dcto);
          //var cadena="hola";
          var cadena="&serie=<?php echo $serie; ?>&numlinea="+numlinea+"&codigo="+codigo+"&codfam="+codfam+"&cantidad="+cantidad+"&precio="+precio+"&importe="+importe+"&descrip="+descrip+"&dcto="+dcto+"&modificado=1";
          //alert("modificar_linea.php?numdocumentotmp=<?php echo $numdocumentotmp ?>&numlinea=<?php echo $numlinea; ?>"+cadena);
          parent.location.href="modificar_linea.php?numdocumentotmp=<?php echo $numdocumentotmp ?>&numlinea=<?php echo $numlinea; ?>"+cadena;
          //parent.window.close();
        }
        function actualiza_importe()
        {
          var precio=document.getElementById("precio").value;
          var cantidad=document.getElementById("cantidad").value;
          var descuento=document.getElementById("dcto").value;
          descuento=descuento/100;
          total=precio*cantidad;
          descuento=total*descuento;
          total=total-descuento;
          var original=parseFloat(total);
          var result=Math.round(original*100)/100 ;
          document.getElementById("importe").value=result;
        }
        function cancelar(){
          parent.window.close();
          //                    aceptar();
        }

      </script>
    <body>
      <table width="900px" cellspacing=0 cellpadding=3 border=0>
        <tr >
          <td class="cabeceraTabla" width="100px">Nº linea</td><td class="itemParTabla" width="750"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $numlinea ?>" name="numlinea" id="numlinea" class="cajaPequena"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
          <td class="cabeceraTabla" width="100px">Codigo</td><td class="itemImarTabla" width="750"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $codigo ?>" name="codigo" id="codigo" class="cajaPequena"></td>
        </tr>
          <tr >
          <td class="cabeceraTabla" width="100px">Codigo familia</td><td class="itemParTabla" width="750"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $codfam ?>" name="codfam" id="codfam" class="cajaPequena"></td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="cabeceraTabla" width="100px">Descripcion</td><td class="itemImparTabla" width="750"><textarea rows="4" cols="99"  name="descrip" id="descrip" ><?php echo utf8_encode($descripcion) ?></textarea>

<!--<input type="text" value=<?php //echo $descrip ?> name="descrip" id="descrip"  class="cajaExtraGrande" >--></td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td class="cabeceraTabla" width="100px">Cantidad</td><td class="itemParTabla" width="750"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $cantidad ?>" name="cantidad" id="cantidad" class="cajaPequena" onChange="actualiza_importe()"></td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td class="cabeceraTabla" width="100px">Precio</td><td class="itemImparTabla" width="750"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $precio ?>" name="precio" id="precio" class="cajaPequena" onChange="actualiza_importe()"></td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td class="cabeceraTabla" width="100px">Dcto.</td><td class="itemParTabla" width="750"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $dcto ?>" name="dcto" id="dcto" class="cajaPequena" onChange="actualiza_importe()"></td>
        </tr><tr>
          <td class="cabeceraTabla" width="100px">Importe</td><td class="itemImparTabla" width="750"><input type="text"  name="importe"  id="importe" value="<?php echo $importe; ?>" class="cajaPequena" readonly ></td>
      </tr>
      <tr><td><a href="javascript:aceptar()"><img src="../img/botonaceptar.jpg" alt="aceptar"></a></td><td><a href="javascript:cancelar()"><img src="../img/botoncancelar.jpg" alt="cancelar"></a></td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
```

he probado de varias formas y no he conseguido mas avances, espero que se entienda la pregunta.

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende, por favor identa los ejemplos y explica mejor el contexto. Si es posible dinos también por qué quieres hacer esto, para entender el contexto y eventualmente sugerirte una mejor solución.

Comment: es para un programa de facturación web, para poder cambiar el orden de los artículos en la factura, no entendí que quieres decir con identa los ejemplos, pero edite la pregunta para ver si asi se entiende mejor.

Comment: ojala pudiese explicarme mejor

Comment: aclaro tambien que no tengo mucha idea de javascript y que no se si es posible hacer lo que quiero

Comment: o si es posible hacerlo con php solo

Comment: he de añadir también que el programa en cuestión es "codeka" por si alguien lo ha usado y mejorado o convertido a mysqli como intento hacer yo.

Comment: No entiendo lo que dices de ordenar, en el 1er bloque están ordenados empezando por `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` y quieres un resultado `3, 2, 1, 4, 5`. ¿?

Comment: mas o menos @A.Cedano lo que quiero es poder cambiar un valor de la celda item que se ve en la imagen, que al cambiar por ejemplo el item "3" al "5" el que era el numero "5" coja el valor "3" y que este cambio se guarde en la BD he probado a hacerlo de diversas maneras a traves de php y no he conseguido nada ya que al cambiar el valor en la segunda consulta que hago me encuentra los dos valores "identicos" y falla la consulta

Comment: Según entiendo quieres lograr cambiar datos dinamicamente sin usar otra ventana u recargar esta misma, es lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: @MiguelClavijo creo que eso es lo que estoy buscando si.

Comment: Como pueda que no sea lo que buscas, pero cumple con requerimiento que me dices te dejo un [Ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24583/enviar-post-a-php-por-medio-de-ajax) de como lo puedes lograr.

Comment: después de probar y probar de mil maneras mirando la estructura de la BD vi que el campo que quiero modificar es un campo auto_increment así que tengo que quitar el autoincrement en la BD y hacer un increment en php para que no interfiera con el update del campo.