# PHP Submit mail() sin salir de la página

Tags: php, html, email, script

En PHP tengo puesto para que envie un mensaje a mi correo en base a las variables cogidas del FORM del HTML, pero no se como hacer para que cuando le de al boton de SUBMIT me salga un mensaje debajo del boton donde ponga "Enviado" en vez de irse a la pagina de php.

HTML (index.html):

```
        <form action="php/email.php" method="post" class="container contact" name="send_email">
            <div class="contact-inputs title">
                <h1>Explicanos <span class="change-how">tu proyecto</span></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-inputs name">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="" placeholder="Nombre y apellidos" class="form-input input-name">
            </div>
            <div class="contact-inputs email">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="" placeholder="Email" class="form-input input-email">
            </div>
            <div class="contact-inputs phone">
                <input type="number" name="phone" id="" placeholder="Teléfono" class="form-input input-phone">
            </div>
            <div class="contact-inputs message">
                <textarea type="radio" name="message" id="" placeholder="Mensaje" class="form-input input-message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="contact-inputs submit">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="ENVIAR" class="btn-submit disabled-button">
            </div>
        </form>
```

PHP (email.php):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $to_email = "correo@gmail.com";
    $subject =  "Cliente: " . $_POST['name'];
    $body = "Telefono: " . $_POST['phone'] . "\n\n" . "Correo: ". $_POST['email'] . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $headers = "De: ". $_POST['email'];

    if (mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        echo "Enviado";
    } else {
        echo "No enviado";
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: Has probado hacerlo con AJAX?

Comment: @JheymanMejia Pues no la verdad, habria que modificar muchas cosas para poder hacerlo?

Comment: En realidad no mucho, necesitas almacenar los inputs que recibes del formulario en un data y luego en el success del AJAX hacer un response que llama a un ID dentro de tu HTML, allí se mostrará el mensaje de confirmación. Por acá hay varios ejemplos https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/24583 o en Google: "PHP MAIL AJAX"